# How sensible is the limit from above against infinity in nonstandard analysis?

Tags: limits, nonstandard-analysis

In nonstandard analysis, we have hyperreal numbers that are greater than any real number. As such, we can create a sequence of infinite, hyperfinite hyperreal numbers which grows ever smaller.

More specifically if we can find such a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in M}$ such that for every hyperreal number $h\in{^*\mathbb R}$ we have $x_i <h$ for some $i\in M$, this sequence feels like a general way of defining a limit that runs against infinity, but from above.

I.e. if $f$ is a function, I am interested in $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$.

I've named the index of the sequence $M$ because I'm not sure how $M$ should look like.

The concept seems interesting enough that I hope that somebody may have taken the time to find out whether it can be made precise in a meaningful way.

As such I'm looking for papers or similar which investigate this concept, and especially if it is even possible to define the limit from above in a meaningful way.

Comment: There is nothing particularly insightful here. It looks and behaves just like $\lim_{n \to \infty} f\left(\frac 1n\right)$, other than where the limit is taken, of course. But where the limit is taken, also doesn't look any different than the neighborhood of $0$, from the view point of limits. People think $\infty$ is some exotic thing, but topologically (i.e., as far as limiting behavior goes) it is no different than ordinary real numbers.